# Dynamically defining an arbitrary number of functions in javascript at runtime

Tags: javascript

I am developing an application that requires the user to provide some JSON data in a file. For each JSON object read-in, I need to define a trainer.on() function -- see code below. Thus, I need to be able to dynamically define an arbitrary number of trainer.on() functions at runtime. Currently, I am doing it like this:

```
  for (var obj in gestures) {
      trainer.fromJSON(JSON.stringify(gestures[obj]));

      alert(gestures[obj].name);

      trainer.on(gestures[obj].name, function() {
        alert('Recognized ' + gestures[obj].name);
      });    
  }
```

However, this approach only seems to define a single trainer.on() function (for the very last gesture that was read in). I'm not sure how to programmatically approach the problem of defining functions dynamically like this in JavaScript...

Note that if I were to do this manually for each read-in object, it would look something like this:

```
trainer.on('One', function() { alert('Recognized One!'); });
trainer.on('Two', function() { alert('Recognized Two!'); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) can help here to capture the variable in the scope you expect when you wire up the event handler.  This is the concept:

```
for (var obj in gestures) {
  trainer.fromJSON(JSON.stringify(gestures[obj]));

   (function(name) {
        trainer.on(name, function() {
            alert('Recognized ' + name);
        });
     }) (gestures[obj].name);

  alert(gestures[obj].name);
}
```